# Implement pagination in a vertical grid

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-paging-3

I am trying to implement pagination in a vertical grid. I have successfully build it with lazyColumn, but for some reason it does not work for lazyVerticalGrid. Here is my code :

```
@Composable
fun <T : TMDbItem> PagingScreen(viewModel: BasePagingViewModel<T>) {
    val lazyTMDbItems = viewModel.pagingDataFlow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(COLUMN_COUNT),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(
            start = GRID_SPACING,
            end = GRID_SPACING,
            bottom = WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(LocalDensity.current).toDp().dp.plus(
                GRID_SPACING
            )
        ),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(GRID_SPACING, Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        content = {

            items(lazyTMDbItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val tmdbItem = lazyTMDbItems.peek(index)
                tmdbItem?.let {
                    TMDbItemContent(
                        tmdbItem,
                        Modifier
                            .height(320.dp)
                            .padding(vertical = GRID_SPACING)
                    )
                }
            }

            lazyTMDbItems.apply {
                when {
                    loadState.refresh is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        item { LoadingView(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) }
                    }
                    loadState.append is LoadState.Loading -> {
                        item { LoadingItem() }
                    }
                    loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val e = lazyTMDbItems.loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
                        item {
                            ErrorScreen(
                                message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                refresh = { retry() }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val e = lazyTMDbItems.loadState.append as LoadState.Error
                        item {
                            ErrorScreen(
                                message = e.error.localizedMessage!!,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .padding(8.dp),
                                refresh = { retry() }
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
```

It loads the 1st two pages, but not the third page and later, Is there anything missing in my implementation? Code can be found here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loads are triggered by the [`LazyPagingItems::get`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/787d7f5099d28f0ca33ff4dfd12b77e9c47baac8:paging/paging-compose/src/main/java/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems.kt;l=129;bpv=0;bpt=0) method. The other method, [`LazyPagingItems::peek`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/787d7f5099d28f0ca33ff4dfd12b77e9c47baac8:paging/paging-compose/src/main/java/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems.kt;l=141;bpv=0;bpt=0) that you are using specifically says:

> Returns the presented item at the specified position, without notifying Paging of the item access that would normally trigger page loads.

Therefore, just calling `get` instead of `peek` should fix that. If you want to specify keys for your items (which you should), you have to use `peek` in the key factory, because key is evaluated for all items, even those that are not visible, so calling `get` there will trigger load immediately.

You can look at [`LazyListScope::items`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/787d7f5099d28f0ca33ff4dfd12b77e9c47baac8:paging/paging-compose/src/main/java/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems.kt;l=301;bpv=0;bpt=0) extension function that is part of paging-compose library and create similar extension for `LazyGridScope`.

Comment: +1 for your help. get solved the problem, another issue that I faced is location of loading and error message. It always displayed at top-left corner of the screen, but I want it to be center. When using LazyColumn I fixed it using Modifier.fillParentMaxSize() and Modifier.fillMaxWidth() as you can see in my sample, but how about lazyVerticalGrid?

Comment: I would probably put it out of the grid. Create one top level Box and put inside the grid and `refresh` loading/error composables on same level.

Comment: I'd need to see the code to know what is wrong...